# jquery-ui datpicker image not showing when deployed to server

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui

My jquery datepicker image is being displayed correctly when it run on local but when it is not being displayed when run on server .
 // apply mask and attach datepickers

```
 $("input.masked-input-date")
 .not("[readonly='readonly']")
  .mask("99/99/9999", { placeholder: "_" })
   .datepicker({
  buttonImage: "../static/images/calendar.png",
  buttonImageOnly: true,
  showOn: "both",
  showButtonPanel: true,
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true
            });
```

My folder structure is root/static/images/calender.png .But when i deployed in the server it is not picked up as http://xxxxx.xxx.org/static/images/calendar.png. Instead it should be http://xxxxx.xx.org/jost/static/images/calendar.png.I have tried but i am believing there is problem in loading the image . Any pointers please?

Answer (score 0):

Try using ASP.NET to get the correct path to the file. Notice I made the path root relative.

```
buttonImage: '<%# Server.MapPath("~/jost/static/images/calendar.png") %>',
```

Comment: buttonImage: "../static/images/calendar.png", to buttonImage: "../jost/static/images/calendar.png" .It is working in server but not local

Comment: i tried your code it is not displaying the image either.